# How can i dynamically pass variables to a PHP script call within setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script here that is supposed to load a php script output into a specified 'div' within set intervals, and be able to apply filters by means of sending values from two 'select' lists to that script.
I have realized the first thing with some help from another topic here on Stack, it's listed in $(document).ready() event. But then i have $("#status_filter").change() and $("#car_filter").change() events. They are supposed to first stop refreshId interval function, then change variables that i am supposed to send to PHP script, reload content with changed variables and start refreshId loop again. As a result, i have the loop working with zero values, but browser doesn't react to selecting options from the list. I've been playing with the code parts for a while now, but to no avail. Please, help me if you can.

```
var status_filter = 0;
var car_filter = 0;

$("#status_filter").change(function() {
    clearInterval(refreshId);
    status_filter = $(this).val();
    $("#content").load("get_orders.php?status=" + status_filter + "&car=" + car_filter);
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#content").load("get_orders.php?status=" + status_filter + "&car=" + car_filter);
    }, 30000);
});

$("#car_filter").change(function() (
    clearInterval(refreshId);
    car_filter = $(this).val();
    $("#content").load("get_orders.php?status=" + status_filter + "&car=" + car_filter);
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#content").load("get_orders.php?status=" + status_filter + "&car=" + car_filter);
    }, 30000);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#filterBar").load("get_filters.php");
    $("#content").load("get_orders.php?status=" + status_filter + "&car=" + car_filter);
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#content").load("get_orders.php?status=" + status_filter + "&car=" + car_filter);
    }, 30000);
});
```

I have this script placed in the page's head 'head' tag. I haven't checked yet if placing all script in a separate file and linking it could help, though. I also fear that believing in js keeping it's variables alive until the page's closed or browser is shut down is wrong.

Comment: add `var refreshId;` up top to make it a global variable, and then inside the change functions, you can call `clearInterval(refreshId);` before reassigning it.

Comment: Thanks, Brian, it's good to be reminded of scopes. Also, my problem's slightly changed. You see, i use to load my filter block with . load() above, right? So, SELECTs are echoed by a PHP script. There's no typo in their ids for sure. Now, when i add a SELECT with the same id to the resulting HTML manually, my script actually works! Also, it doesn't require stopping setInterval() function, so no need to fix it. So, the question now is: why the hell does not it work for .load()-ed SELECT with identical id?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `setTimeout()`? You can create an easy looping function using this. The code below will print out a number every second, then call itself again.

```js
$(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  var loop = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('body').append(++counter);
      loop();
    }, 1000);
  }
  loop();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This can be tailored for you to a looping function like this:

```
function loop(status, car) {
//Check Values of status and car, set defaults otherwise.
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#content").load("get_orders.php?status=" + status + "&car=" + car);
          loop();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Isn't setTimeout() a one-time function? And i have setInterval() working for me perfectly. It is .change() method and/or maybe something else that's giving me hard time now.